# Get raw transaction from transaction Id using web3js or something similar in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ethereum

So i will give an example let's say i have the transaction id https://etherscan.io/tx/0xafef64d0d03db9f13c6c3f8aec5902167ea680bd0ffa0268d89a426d624b2ae1

In etherscan i can use their menu to see the raw transaction which will be

```
0xf8a915850516aab3ad82be7c947d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb080b844095ea7b300000000000000000000000022b1cbb8d98a01a3b71d034bb899775a76eb1cc2ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff26a003daa35e6aa4a7cd439133411a390ff0796420d5cb39e9e276db75b01218ed41a028605f36c601527bd435b36da5403ee972fc2fb2c8f70959199bcdba0d0e8c77
```

I can't get this with etherscan api or geth rpc , i have found eth_getRawTransaction but it give just 0x for transfer transaction is there anyway i can find the raw transaction using nodejs code

thank you

I think i need to rlp encode the transaction or something like that , i'm lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A raw transaction is an object. This hex string represents a [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) transaction object.

Example code below.

Note that `ethers` requires you to parse out the signature and other params of an already mined/validated transaction, and pass the signature as a second argument. There's probably a more generic way of doing that, I couldn't think of any right now.

```
const tx = await provider.getTransaction("0xafef64d0d03db9f13c6c3f8aec5902167ea680bd0ffa0268d89a426d624b2ae1");

const unsignedTx = {
    to: tx.to,
    nonce: tx.nonce,
    gasLimit: tx.gasLimit,
    gasPrice: tx.gasPrice,
    data: tx.data,
    value: tx.value,
    chainId: tx.chainId
};
const signature = {
    v: tx.v,
    r: tx.r,
    s: tx.s
}

const serialized = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(unsignedTx, signature);
console.log(serialized);
```

Docs:

- https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getTransaction
- https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/transactions/#utils-serializeTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers
for the ones looking if you are hosting your own geth node , it doesn't index all the transactions

You need to run:

```
geth with --txlookuplimit 0
```

Then, the rpc call `eth_getRawTransactionByHash` will do the job
my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Based on Petr's answer, but with EIP-1559 fields and TypeScript.
This is the code for Ethers v5.

```
import { Transaction } from "@ethersproject/transactions";

/**
 * Serializes a transaction object into a raw transaction string.
 * This function takes a Transaction object, ensures it is fully signed,
 * constructs the unsigned transaction object, and then serializes it with the signature.
 * It also verifies the serialization process by comparing the computed transaction hash
 * with the original transaction hash.
 *
 * @param {Transaction} transaction - The transaction object from Ethers.js.
 * @returns {string} The serialized raw transaction.
 */
const transactionToRawTransaction = (
  transaction: TransactionResponse,
): string => {
  const type0Fields = { gasPrice: transaction.gasPrice };
  const type1Fields = { ...type0Fields, accessList: transaction.accessList };
  const type2Fields = {
    accessList: transaction.accessList,
    maxFeePerGas: transaction.maxFeePerGas,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: transaction.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
  };
  const typeFileds = [type0Fields, type1Fields, type2Fields];
  const extraFields = typeFileds[transaction.type ?? 0];
  const unsignedTx = {
    chainId: transaction.chainId,
    data: transaction.data,
    gasLimit: transaction.gasLimit,
    nonce: transaction.nonce,
    to: transaction.to,
    type: transaction.type,
    value: transaction.value,
    ...extraFields,
  };
  assert.ok(transaction.r);
  const signature = {
    r: transaction.r,
    s: transaction.s,
    v: transaction.v,
  };
  const serialized = ethers.utils.serializeTransaction(unsignedTx, signature);
  // double check things went well
  assert.strictEqual(ethers.utils.keccak256(serialized), transaction.hash);
  return serialized;
};

/**
 * Fetches a transaction from the blockchain using its hash and serializes it into a raw transaction string.
 * This function retrieves the transaction details using the provided hash, ensuring the transaction exists,
 * and then utilizes `transactionToRawTransaction` to serialize the transaction.
 * This is useful if we want to replay a raw transaction in local or in the tests.
 *
 * @param {Provider} provider - The Ethers.js provider instance to interact with the blockchain.
 * @param {string} hash - The hash of the transaction to fetch and serialize.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} A promise that resolves to the serialized raw transaction string.
 */
const transactionHashToRawTransaction = async (
  provider: Provider,
  hash: string,
): Promise<string> => {
  const transaction = await provider.getTransaction(hash);
  const serialized = transactionToRawTransaction(transaction);
  return serialized;
};
```

It's much easier with Ethers v6 is much easier since the `ethers.Transaction` object has a `serialized` attribute.

```
import { TransactionResponseParams } from "ethers";

const transactionToRawTransaction = (
  transaction: TransactionResponseParams,
): string => {
  const serialized = Transaction.from(transaction).serialized;
  // double check things went well
  assert.strictEqual(keccak256(serialized), transaction.hash);
  return serialized;
};
```